# Vista/Ubuntu install problem

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to decide on installing Ubuntu along with my windows vista.  I copied the install files to my windows and installed from there.  Everything seem to go okay and I assumed that Ubuntu install created another partition for me, but I'm not sure.  Anyway, Ubuntu started up nice and runs nice, but when I booted to Ubuntu, I found that I lost my authentication.

Is there a way to restore that without going through Microsoft?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by  _I lost my authentication_. Anyways, can you describe better what procedure did you use and what happened later?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by authentication?

A brief summary of the installation process should clarify what has happened and how to enter your username and password.

Normally you install from the live CD you created in Windows or whatever OS you started out with. To install you boot the live CD and--assuming you want to keep your other OS and files--tell it to install *alongside* other operating systems.

Alternatively, you might run the Wubi installer, which installs Ubuntu to a disk image file *inside* the existing Windows partition. This also keeps the Windows system.

I'm not sure which way you insatlled. But either way, during installation, it asks you to create a username and password, copies files, and restarts. You then get a boot menu where you can select between Ubuntu and Windows. To use Ubuntu, select it, and once it has booted, type in the  user name and password your gave it when you set it up.

If you don't *remember* the username and password you put in when you installed, or if the username and password you installed with are *not working*, then we'll need to know whether you booted from a CD/DVD/USB to install Ubuntu or installed Ubuntu inside Windows with Wubi--the way you'd fix it will be different in each case.

<sup>If the problem is that your username and password are now rejected when you try to log on to your *Windows* system, that's very strange, and you should provide a more detailed description of exactly what you're seeing. If this was triggered by installing Ubuntu, that's quite unusual.</sup>

Comment: If my recent edit removes anything important from your answer or otherwise doesn't express what you want to, please feel free to edit it further and/or comment to let me know. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Thanks Eliah...sorry for the poor explanation.  Hard to tell what happened.  I'm finding my Windows directory under the directory "Host" in the Ubuntu Directories.  Is this a normal directory??? Did I screw up my windows when I installed Ubuntu????